# Changing Number to Letter Grades

Tags: c

I am trying to figure out why I cannot get the number to change to a letter. There seems to be something I am missing when returning the char function to the main function, but I cannot figure it out. When I print it, it will not print out the letter. I would really appreciate some guidance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char letter(int grade);

int main()
{
   int score; //taken as user input
   int grade;

   printf("\tEnter your numerical grade: ");
   scanf("%i", score);

   letter(grade);

   printf("Your grade is a %i", grade);



   return 0;
}


char letter(int grade)
{
  switch(grade/10) 
  {
    case 10:
    {
        return 'A';
        break;
    }
    case 9:
    {
        return 'A';
        break;

    }
    case 8:
    {
        return 'B';
        break;
    }
    case 7:
    {
        return 'C';
        break;
    }
    case 6:
    {
        return 'D';
        break;
    }
    case 5:
    {
        return 'D';
        break;
    }
  return grade;
  }
}
```

Comment: You threw away the result of `findLetter(grade);` It returned the value but you did not put that in a variable or output it. Note that `char findLetter(int grade)` passes grade by value (meaning passes a copy) so any change to `grade` inside the function will not be seen outside the function.

Comment: @Holli This call scanf("%i", score) is invalid. You have to write scanf("%i", &score) or better scanf("%d", &score)

Comment: `findLetter` has undefined behaviour for any parameters outside of the range `[50, 100]`: `return grade;` is never actually executed, since it's part of `case 5` which always returns before that statement and even if it was part of the default case, simply returning the input unmodified is likely not the behaviour you intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not stored the result of `findLetter(grade)`. Change it to:

```
int main()
{
   int score; //taken as user input
   char grade;

   printf("\tEnter your numerical grade: ");
      scanf(" %d", &score);

      grade = findLetter(score);

      printf("Your grade is a %d", grade);

      return 0;
   }
```

Also in the function `char findLetter(int grade)` you are returning `grade` which is an `int`, may be change it to

```
return 'E';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the function `findLetter(grade)`, I think you should pass the score to it and the grade is of type char.  Assign the return of that function to the grade like so:

```
int main()
{
   int score; //taken as user input
   char grade;

   printf("\tEnter your numerical grade: ");
   scanf("%i", &score);

   grade = findLetter(score);

   printf("Your grade is a %c", grade);



   return 0;
}
```